# Entity Framework generated SQL is slow

Tags: entity-framework-5

The way Entity framework generates the SQL queries are slowing down the site or putting a lot of pressure on the cpu.

The code we currently have is

```
        var items = (from item in _DatabaseContext.ViewDashboardCounts
            where item.EmployeeID == employeeId && item.BranchID == branchId
            select item);
```

The query generated from this is

```
SELECT  
   [Extent1].[EmployeeID] AS [EmployeeID], [Extent1].[C1] AS [C1], [Extent1].[C2] AS [C2],  
   [Extent1].[C3] AS [C3], [Extent1].[C4] AS [C4], [Extent1].[C5] AS [C5],  
   [Extent1].[C6] AS [C6], [Extent1].[C7] AS [C7], [Extent1].[C8] AS [C8],  
   [Extent1].[C9] AS [C9], [Extent1].[BranchID] AS [BranchID] 
FROM 
   (SELECT  
       [vDashboardCounts].[EmployeeID] AS [EmployeeID],  
       [vDashboardCounts].[BranchID] AS [BranchID], [vDashboardCounts].[C1] AS [C1],  
       [vDashboardCounts].[C2] AS [C2], [vDashboardCounts].[C3] AS [C3],  
       [vDashboardCounts].[C4] AS [C4], [vDashboardCounts].[C5] AS [C5],  
       [vDashboardCounts].[C6] AS [C6], [vDashboardCounts].[C7] AS [C7],  
       [vDashboardCounts].[C8] AS [C8], [vDashboardCounts].[C9] AS [C9] 
    FROM 
       [dbo].[vDashboardCounts] AS [vDashboardCounts]
) 
AS [Extent1] 
WHERE ([Extent1].[EmployeeID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[BranchID] = @p__linq__1)
```

However this runs for 2 seconds, which is very slow, however this is still faster than our previous query, but if I move the "where" to inside query (`[dbo].[vDashboardCounts] AS [vDashboardCounts]`) then the execution becomes instant

This is our first code

```
var items = (from item in _DatabaseContext.ViewDashboardCounts
            where item.EmployeeID == employeeId && item.BranchID == branchId
            select new List<int?>
            {
                item.C1,
                item.C2,
                item.C3,
                item.C4,
                item.C5,
                item.C6,
                count,
                item.C8,
                item.C9
            });
```

It took around 11 seconds to execute but I changed this code to

```
        var items = (from item in _DatabaseContext.ViewDashboardCounts
            where item.EmployeeID == employeeId && item.BranchID == branchId
            select item);
        return items.ToList().Select(item => new List<int?>
            {
                item.C1,
                item.C2,
                item.C3,
                item.C4,
                item.C5,
                item.C6,
                count,
                item.C8,
                item.C9
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

What can I do to speed up the execution of the first piece of code because the view vDashboardCounts
Doesn't even take a second to execute all the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query looks pretty basic I don't think that you should tinker around that. First of all you can try to use [AsNoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx):

```
    _DatabaseContext.ViewDashboardCounts.AsNoTracking()
.Where(item => item.EmployeeID == employeeId && item.BranchID == branchId).ToList()
```

Then check if you have indexes for EmployeeID and/or BranchID. If still not happy with result may be worth to [partition your database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188232(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Seemed to have worked quite nice, Though im going to take a look at indexing the view, I have never done that before